# Xamarin Android Native Crashing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having some problems with a Native crash on Xamarin Android. It seems to occur when navigating in and out of views, although it occasionally occurs just when in a view. I have tried using resources monitor, and the CPU and RAM usage are both fine. I enabled all exception break points in Visual Studio, and got the following debug log (removed the middle part).

```
07-26 16:18:16.957 E/mono-rt (13327): /proc/self/maps:
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 12c00000-52c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:04 20648                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space) (deleted)
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 6f867000-6fa4d000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318946                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 6fa4d000-6fb0a000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318947                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-core-libart.art
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 6fb0a000-6fb47000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318948                             /
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 70167000-7016e000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318956                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-ims-common.art
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 7016e000-70183000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318957                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-apache-xml.art
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 70183000-701a1000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318958                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-org.apache.http.legacy.boot.art
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 701a1000-701a2000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318959                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.art
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 701a2000-701a5000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 318960 
                        /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.art
07-26 16:18:16.958 E/mono-rt (13327): 701a5000-70375000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 1248                               /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
07-26 16:18:16.990 E/mono-rt (13327): f5209000-f520a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [anon:linker_alloc_small_objects]
07-26 16:18:16.991 E/mono-rt (13327): f529e000-f52e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
07-26 16:18:16.991 E/mono-rt (13327): f52e6000-f52e7000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
07-26 16:18:16.991 F/libc    (13327): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0x3 in tid 13327 (draulic.can2lan) (draulic.can2lan)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe it is a memory leak issue in your app. Please check once

Comment: I've tried using the Resource Monitor in Android Studio and my memory usage is always around 100MB, with no spikes so I don't think it's a leak.